# accessing sibling key values in JavaScript object in gulp config file

Tags: javascript, object, gulp

I have a config object inside my gulpfile.js similar to this.

```
var config = {
    sass: {
        source: '...',
        dest: '...',
        config: {
            style: 'compressed',
            errLogToConsole: false
        },
        ...
    },
    notify: {
        ...
    },
    ...
    somethingElse: {
        rootPath: '/some/specific/path',
        folderName: '/projectRootFolder',
        someValueThatReuseTwoDeclaredAbove: this.rootPath   this.folderName,
        anotherKey: this.someValueThatReuseTwoDeclaredAbove   '/vendor'
    }
};
```

*I want to reuse my variables* declared under section `somethingElse` similar to in the preview object.

When I try to access them like this `this.somethingElse.rootPath` I get error `Cannot read property 'rootPath' of undefined`. When I try to access it like this `this.rootPath` then I don't get the error but the files are never copied to the location specified in the config. **How can I access keys from within current object so I can reuse their value when declaring variables?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just do your config in multiple steps:

```
var somethingElseConfig = {
    rootPath: '/some/specific/path',
    folderName: '/projectRootFolder',
};
somethingElseConfig.someValueThatReuseTwoDeclaredAbove = somethingElseConfig.rootPath + somethingElseConfig.folderName;
somethingElseConfig.anotherKey = somethingElseConfig.someValueThatReuseTwoDeclaredAbove + '/vendor';

var config = {
    //...
    somethingElse: somethingElseConfig,
    //...
};
```

---

> How can I access keys from within current object so I can reuse their value when declaring variables?

In javascript, you can't.

Actually there is no *current object*, because the object is not yet created. So you can't access properties of a not-yet-existing object.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but this is more or less how I got it as a workaround already. I want to have it as one object. Mainly because I am learning JS and I want to know how to the future. The other reason is that I like it that way. There must be some elegant way to do this directly. I am going to wait for a while if someone would be kind enough to help me or at least point me to the right direction. If nobody shows up I will accept your answer as a workaround for other people even though it didnt helped me.

Comment: @theStudent You can't in javascript. (I wonder if there is another language in which you can)

Comment: Hmmm thats strange. I know that it is possible like this `this.key` for the normal "level" object. It's also something that I would expect as a feature to be includes in the language itself. But maybe youre right. I am still learning JavaScript and it sounds like you know more than I do. I know that JS does not support encapsulation either so it could be right. I know that it will be or already is for a while in the new revision. Well thank you for your time I will leave it be for now.

Comment: @theStudent I found [this workaround](http://jsfiddle.net/s0vh10dd/), but I don't think it's a good practice used this way

Comment: Thank you. Yes it looks kinda messy with that function expression and json parsing. I've just made a quick test and files were copied to the desired dir. I hope there are no side effects. I will have to check later when I'll have some free time if everything is working as intended. Anyway since I have more than one nested object that needs to reuse these values it's cleaner this way than having multiple object all over the place. Shame that JS doesn't have built in file includes. What I ended up doing was `config = JSON.stringify(config, null, '    ');` and then `config = JSON.parse(config);`